# Getting Facebook friends in background thread in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, facebook, facebook-graph-api, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to get the Facebook friends of the current user using `[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler]` the code works well when calling it from main thread but it never enter the completion handler when i call it from background thread

```
- (void)getFacebookFirneds {
    [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                              id result,
                                                              NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // this code is not reached !!
        }    
    }];
}
```

i.e. when i call `[self getFacebookFirneds]` it works, but When i use `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getFacebookFirneds) withObject:nil];`
 it never enter the completion handler, don't know why!

I have also tried `FBRequest` and got the same result

```
- (void)getFacebookFirneds {
    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // this code is not reached !!
        }    
    }];
}
```

I also tried to use GCD instead of `performSelectorInBackground` and got the same result

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    [self getFacebookFriends];
});
```

Comment: Most of the FBRequest handler invoked on main thread, check the documentation. may be its one of them

Comment: Is it so necessary to make request from background thread? startWithCompletionHandler - async already.  Maybe there are some  restrictions from FB sdk...

Comment: i do a long process in the Completion Handler that is why i want to call it in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your handler take time to process friends you can call `[self getFacebookFriends]` in main thread and process the friends array in background 
i.e.

```
- (void)getFacebookFriends {
    [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                              id result,
                                                              NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSArray *facebookFriends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processFacebookFriends: ) withObject:facebookFriends];
        }    
    }];
}

- (void)processFacebookFriends:(NSArray *)facebookFriends {
// put your code here
}
```